# Converting list to list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I convert the list of strings to list of list as

```
a=['A','B','C']
```

and the converted to

```
b=[['A'],['B'],['C']]
```

Comment: I'm curious why you need this. Most probably, YAGNI.

Answer (score 13):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
In [7]: a = ['A', 'B', 'C']

In [8]: b = [[item] for item in a]

In [9]: b
Out[9]: [['A'], ['B'], ['C']]
```

Answer (score 7):

use a list comprehension :

```
>>> a=['A','B','C']
>>> [list(x) for x in a]
[['A'], ['B'], ['C']]
```

or use `map()`, in python 3.x `map()` returns a map object so use `list(map(list,a))` there:

```
>>> map(list,a)
[['A'], ['B'], ['C']]
```

or as @mata points out, if you want something like this:

```
>>> a=['foo','bar','spam']
>>> [[x] for x in a]
[['foo'], ['bar'], ['spam']]
```

or with `map()`:

```
In [1]: a=['foo','bar','spam']

In [2]: map(lambda x:[x],a)
Out[2]: [['foo'], ['bar'], ['spam']]
```

Comment: `list` on a string doesn't produce a list with the string in it. this example only works by accident here.

Comment: because this does only work for single character strings. try it with longer strings, or ints then you'll see...

Comment: @mata added your version too.