# Convert list into list of lists

Tags: python, list

I want to convert list into list of list. Example:

```
my_list = ['banana', 'mango', 'apple']
```

I want:

```
my_list = [['banana'], ['mango'], ['apple']]
```

I tried:

```
list(list(my_list))
```

Comment: This question may be duplicated to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109325/converting-list-to-list-of-list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting list to list of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109325/converting-list-to-list-of-list)

Answer (score 31):

Use list comprehension

```
[[i] for i in lst]
```

It iterates over each item in the list and put that item into a new list.

*Example:*

```
>>> lst = ['banana', 'mango', 'apple']
>>> [[i] for i in lst]
[['banana'], ['mango'], ['apple']]
```

If you apply `list` func on each item, it would turn each item which is in string format to a list of strings.

```
>>> [list(i) for i in lst]
[['b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a'], ['m', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'o'], ['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e']]
>>>
```

Comment: What about map? I like this `map(list, lst)`

Comment: Lol can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: @khredos check blwo answer for map

Comment: @khredos `map` will work like `[list(i) for i in lst]`

Comment: @RahulKP you're right, but what I proposed is less verbose. I just want to konw what makes it a bad idea. I feel like I might already know and it has something to do with representation of map in python 2 vs python 3

Comment: `map` applies the func which was given as first arg to each item in the iterable.. so `map(list, iterable) == [list(i) for i in iterable]` (in python2) And note that `list('foo') != ['foo']`

Comment: @khredos: Possibly because it is frowned upon when cleaner pythonic alternatives such as list comprehensions exist. Although in this particular case it looks very elegant -- I'd probably favor map.

Comment: @Sameer: Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 6):

Try This one Liner:-

```
map(lambda x:[x], my_list)
```

**Result**

```
In [1]: map(lambda x:[x], my_list)
Out[1]: [['banana'], ['mango'], ['apple']]
```

Comment: Although not pythonic, this is a correct answer. Not sure why this was downvoted. Could be be made more concise: `map(list, my_list)`.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan map is little bit slower than list comp.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I prefer readability and elegance over micro optimizations of that nature. If those nanoseconds were worth a lot, I probably choose other languages.

Comment: @UltraInstinct, `map(list, my_list)` does _not_ work. `list(1)` will give a `TypeError`

Comment: @aydow how you defined your list `my_list`

Comment: sorry, that should be it throws an error on a list of `int`s

Comment: @UltraInstinct and @aydow  `list(1)` and `map(list, my_list)` wouldn't work, `list` takes `iterable` as input but in `map(list, my_list)` my_list have values as `scaler` but not `iterable`. Check help(list). so better way is i answered.

Comment: You are right, `map(list, my_list)` would not work. Not sure what I was thinking. I stand by first statement though, list comprehension is more pythonic for this use case.

Answer (score -4):

```
    lst = ['banana', 'mango', 'apple']
    lst_of_lst = []
    for i in lst:
        spl = i.split(',')
        lst_of_lst.append(spl)
    print(lst_of_lst)
```

## first create an empty list and then iterate through your list. split each list and append them to your empty list.

Comment: You don't need to split the elements of the original list you're iterating.