# How to convert multiple list of list into list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data as:

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[ "I am new at programming."],
                   [ "Leaves are falling from tree."]], columns = ['Text'])
```

input file print:

```
    Text
0   I am new at programming.
1   Leaves are falling from tree.
```

and I have a code that performs NLP task:

```
NewListA = []

for inputs in df2['Text']:
    t = nlp(inputs)
    res_A = {}
    for sent in t.sentences:
        for word in sent.words:
            # append to dict
            txt= f'{word.text}'
            upos= f'{word.upos}'
            res_A[txt]= upos

    NewList = list(res_A.items())            
    NewListA.append(NewList)
```

It output as:

```
[[('I', 'PRON'), ('am', 'AUX'), ('new', 'ADJ'), ('at', 'ADP'), ('programming', 'NOUN'), ('.', 'PUNCT')], [('Leaves', 'NOUN'), ('are', 'AUX'), ('falling', 'VERB'), ('from', 'ADP'), ('tree', 'NOUN'), ('.', 'PUNCT')]]
```

This results in an additional outmost list bracket. I want to remove outmost bracket and get:

```
[('I', 'PRON'), ('am', 'AUX'), ('new', 'ADJ'), ('at', 'ADP'), ('programming', 'NOUN'), ('.', 'PUNCT')], [('Leaves', 'NOUN'), ('are', 'AUX'), ('falling', 'VERB'), ('from', 'ADP'), ('tree', 'NOUN'), ('.', 'PUNCT')]
```

where I can convert it to dataframe and end up with this:

```
    POS
0   [('I', 'PRON'), ('am', 'AUX'), ('new', 'ADJ'), ('at', 'ADP'), ('programming', 'NOUN'), ('.', 'PUNCT')]
1   [('Leaves', 'NOUN'), ('are', 'AUX'), ('falling', 'VERB'), ('from', 'ADP'), ('tree', 'NOUN'), ('.', 'PUNCT')]
```

I looked into [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38604805/convert-list-into-list-of-lists) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) however, these removing all brackets inside the list, which not I what I am looking for.

Note: my desire results example is:

`[['A','B'],['B','C']]` --> `['A','B'],['B','C']`

Comment: Can you give an expected result?

Comment: @AnnZen Thanks. I just updated

Comment: @Bilgin are you sure your code is broken? Removing the outermost bracket will have no meaningful effect on your code (see my answer below) and the example you gave should already produce the dataframe you want.

Comment: @Bilgin Perfect. I added an answer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a need to remove the brackets in order to produce your desired result:

```
import pandas as pd

NewListA = [[('I', 'PRON'), ('am', 'AUX'), ('new', 'ADJ'), ('at', 'ADP'), ('programming', 'NOUN'), ('.', 'PUNCT')], [('Leaves', 'NOUN'), ('are', 'AUX'), ('falling', 'VERB'), ('from', 'ADP'), ('tree', 'NOUN'), ('.', 'PUNCT')]]

df = pd.DataFrame({'POS':NewListA})
print(df)
```

Indepently of the size of `NewListA`, you could manage each list by managing the rows of df.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but The size of list changes. Like now i have two list, but  this can change and i dont want to write as: lst1, lst2, ...

Answer (score 0):

You are working with a 2-d array(`NewListA`),

---

Use `NewListA[0]` to get:

```
[('I', 'PRON'), ('am', 'AUX'), ('new', 'ADJ'), ('at', 'ADP'), ('programming', 'NOUN'), ('.', 'PUNCT')]
```

---

Use `NewListA[1]` to get:

```
[('Leaves', 'NOUN'), ('are', 'AUX'), ('falling', 'VERB'), ('from', 'ADP'), ('tree', 'NOUN'), ('.', 'PUNCT')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my input size changes. Do you have any other suggestions to store elements or get rid of outmost bracket?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the outermost bracket from `NewListA`, the result will be an implicit tuple, which should behave identically to a list in your code.

## Example

`[list1, list2, list3]` is a list containing three lists.

`list1, list2, list3` is equivalent to `(list1, list2, list3)`, which is a 3-tuple.

Comment: thanks for comments.  Do you mean to save list into tuple at the end instead of list of list?

Comment: @Bilgin list of tuple and list of list are equivalent in your case. There's probably no problem with your code, as [others have suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62644609/13568555).